# How to add lists to a tibble

Tags: r, list, vectorization, tidyverse, tibble

I am defining two functions as follows:

```
load <- function(rate, servicetime){
    # Calculates Offered Load in Erlang
    # rate: Rate of arrivals
    # servicetime: Mean time for service
    a = rate * servicetime
    return(list(load = a, rate = rate, servicetime = servicetime))
}

erlang.C <- function(load, servers){
    # Returns: 
    # -- p: Percentage of customers who have to wait
    # -- waitingtime: Mean waiting time of a customer
    # load: Offered Load in Erlang from load()
    # servers: Number of serves in use
    if(load$load >= servers){
        warning("Erlang.C not solvable. Increase number of servers.")
        return()
    }
    top <- (load$load^servers) / (factorial(servers) * (1 - (load$load / servers)))
    bottom.summands <- function(load, server){
        # Helper function
        x <- (load$load^server) / factorial(server)
        return(x)
    }
    s <- c(0, seq(servers-1))
    bottom <- bottom.summands(load, s)
    bottom <- sum(bottom)
    bottom <- top + bottom
    eC <- top / bottom
    wt <- (load$servicetime * eC) / (servers - load$load)
    return(list(p = eC, waitingtime = wt))
}
```

Both functions return a list since my intention is to use these lists to carry related values. An example for this is the use of the list returned by `load()` as parameter of the `erlang.C()` function. I consider this useful since `erlang.C()` uses both the `load$load` value as well as the `load$servicetime` value and by using lists there is no risk of using wrong parameter values together.

Now consider the following tibble with input data:

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- tibble(rate = c(0.4, 0.7,1.8),
                  servicetime = c(0.3, 0.75, 1.2))
```

It is easy enough to include the load in this tibble:

```
example <- example %>%
               mutate(load = load(rate, servicetime)$load)
```

However, continuing with the dame logic does not work:

```
example <- example %>%
               mutate(load = load(rate, servicetime)$load,
                      waiting = erlang.C(load = load(rate, servicetime), 2)$waitingtime)
```

1. How can I add the result of `erlang.C()` to the tibble?
2. Is it possible (and if yes, how) to use `mutate()` to add both list entrys to the tibble without calling `erlang.C()` twice?

Comment: Your code is not working, `load$load` is meant to be a vector and this cause problems with `load$load >= servers` and in `(load$load^servers)`.

Comment: Could you try simplifying the question as much as you can please? Ideally the business logic of your code shouldn't appear at all, it should be about basic data structures.